# Need of RHEL 5.4 rpms

Tags: linux, x86-64

I have RHEl 5.4 server . Can any body say a link where can i find the rpm list for RHEl 5.4 version. In net i was not able to find these two rpms. Does anybody has this version of rpm file.

krb5-devel-1.6.1-36.el5

gcc-4.1.2-46.e15

Answer (score 3):

You don't say if you have a paid subscription for RHEL, but if you're willing to get by on the CentOS packages (which are functionally identical), the 5.4 archive is at http://vault.centos.org/5.4/os/x86_64/CentOS/ , which includes the versions of the packages you seek.

Unless they've changed the licence conditions, I doubt you will find the RHEL binaries floating out and about, as no redistribution of the binaries is a condition of the RHEL licence.

Answer (score 0):

```
    rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm

yum install krb gcc
```

Comment: Forgive me, but the rpmforge repository at http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/, which is what the rpmforge package you give points to, has neither gcc nor krb5-devel in it.